MongoDB aggregation: Only keep the running total for the last item in the partition
I have a data like:
[
  { "grp": "A", "seq": 1, "score": 1, x: 0 },
  { "grp": "A", "seq": 1, "score": 2, x: 0 },
  { "grp": "A", "seq": 1, "score": 3, x: 0 },
  { "grp": "A", "seq": 1, "score": 4, x: 0 }
]

Using $setWindowFields,
{
  partitionBy: "$grp",
  sortBy: { seq: 1 },
  output: {
    x: {
      $sum: "$score",
      window: {
        documents: ["unbounded", "current"]
      }
    },
  }
}

I get:
[
  { "grp": "A", "seq": 1, "score": 1, x: 1 },
  { "grp": "A", "seq": 1, "score": 2, x: 3 },
  { "grp": "A", "seq": 1, "score": 3, x: 6 },
  { "grp": "A", "seq": 1, "score": 4, x: 10 }
]

I only need to retain the running sum (x) for the last item of the partition.
[
  { "grp": "A", "seq": 1, "score": 1, x: 0 },
  { "grp": "A", "seq": 1, "score": 2, x: 0 },
  { "grp": "A", "seq": 1, "score": 3, x: 0 },
  { "grp": "A", "seq": 1, "score": 4, x: 10 }
]

I've been testing with $project and $last but I wasn't able to make it work.
What is a better expression or additional stage do I need to use?
Thank you!

https://mongoplayground.net/p/qs7VX9tNKHE something like this?

If you only need x=10 for the last item in the group, then it's not really a running sum. Wouldn't a set, group, unwind be better here? Also, all the seq values are the same so the ordering is not guaranteed ie last may not be last.

@aneroid, seq can be different values and there are a lot of other variables like a date which I intend to use for sorting.

@aneroid, the running sum stage is done. Thus, I moved on to the next stage of masking samples that aren't usable by setting the x to 0.

"masking samples that aren't usable by setting the x to 0" To me, that would be better suited to a group with $last: https://mongoplayground.net/p/HK9NE68nc82 But I suppose you still need the other documents too

@aneroid, you really have good points! yes, I still need the rest of the documents for plotting.

Not sure if there is a deterministic sorting in your dataset, but with the same sorting that you are using, you can assign ordering with $documentNumber in your $setWindowFields. Then, compute $rank with the ordering field. The last document will have rank: 1. You can use this with $cond to conditionally set field x
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      partitionBy: "$grp",
      sortBy: {
        seq: 1
      },
      output: {
        x: {
          $sum: "$score",
          window: {
            documents: [
              "unbounded",
              "current"
            ]
          }
        },
        ordering: {
          $documentNumber: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": "$grp",
      "sortBy": {
        "ordering": -1
      },
      "output": {
        "rank": {
          "$rank": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "ordering": "$$REMOVE",
      "rank": "$$REMOVE",
      "x": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $eq: [
              1,
              "$rank"
            ]
          },
          "then": "$x",
          "else": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

Ray's answer and cmgchess's example are both a better approach than group, shown here. But worth having since you only need the sum on the last item in the group and not exactly a running sum. $setWindowFields is better for an actual running sum, as per the pipeline in your question.
Here, I'm sorting and grouping, then pushing all the docs to the list (so 100MB limit issue may occur), and setting xs the sum of score.
In order to update only the last x to this value, I slice the docs array and set x = xs only on that one, and then unwind.
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $sort: { seq: 1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$grp",
      docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
      xs: { $sum: "$score" }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      docs: {
        $concatArrays: [
          {
            $slice: [
              "$docs",
              { $subtract: [{ $size: "$docs" }, 1] }
            ]
          },
          [
            {
              $setField: {
                field: "x",
                input: { $last: "$docs" },
                value: "$xs"
              }
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$docs" },
  { $replaceWith: "$docs" }
])

Mongo Playground
